# Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA - Ant tastk fails

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ant, build

I recently moved from my Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA. As i tried to build my old Ant-script it somehow fails. Using the same code version and same ant script in Eclipse still works. Now i'm somehow confused if this is some Ant problem or IDE thing.

This is the Ant script part that keeps crashing:

```
    <path id="compile.classpath.kit">
        <pathelement path="${svn.kit}/lib/java/activation.jar" />
        <pathelement path="${svn.kit}/lib/java/mail.jar" />
        <pathelement path="${svn.kit}/lib/java/jdom.jar" />
        <pathelement path="${svn.kit}/lib/java/servlet-api.jar" />
        <pathelement path="${svn.kit}/lib/java/saaj-api.jar" />
        <pathelement path="${svn.kit}/lib/java/jakarta-poi.jar" />
        <pathelement path="${svn.kit}/lib/java/jh.jar" />
        <pathelement path="${svn.kit}/lib/java/ierp.jar" />
        <pathelement path="${svn.kit}/lib/java/icrystal.jar" />
        <pathelement path="${svn.kit}/lib/java/poi.jar" />
        <pathelement path="${svn.kit}/lib/properties/" />
        <pathelement path="${svn.kit}/>

[....shortened it. Many more path entries here...]
</path>

<target name="ddobjekteChecken">
            <java fork="true" classpath="${compile.classpath.kit}" classname="de.integris.kit.ctl.RunJob" failonerror="true">
                <jvmarg value="-Xmx512M"/>
                <classpath path="${java.class.path}" />
                <classpath refid="compile.classpath.kit" />
                <arg line="-user user -passwd pass -dbprops Database -class someclass"/>
            </java>
    </target>
```

My stacktrace looks like this:

```
Java returned: -1
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:111)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:198)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:286)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:30)
```

It seem to have a problem with the `<java fork="true" classpath="${compile.classpath.kit}" classname="de.integris.kit.ctl.RunJob" failonerror="true">` part.

I can't figure out if this is an error in the Ant script or some IntelliJ magic that keeps my script crashing.

Does anybody had similar issues and know what i'm doing wrong?

Edit: This is what IntelliJ shows me: [IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nnJr.jpg)

Comment: Which Java version is used to run the build script (`<echo message="Java version: ${ant.java.version}"/>`) in each IDE?

Comment: Both IDE are configured to use `jdk1.8.0_102`

Comment: According to the last stack trace element, the Ant script is not running in a separate/configured JRE. Please, add `<echo message="Java version: ${ant.java.version}"/>` to your Ant script to see which JRE is used.

Comment: It tells me the same `Java version: 1.8` for both IntelliJ and Eclipse

Comment: Try using a different JDK in the Ant Build File Properties dialog.

Comment: Tried that as well. Also changing Ant versions (1.9.4,1.9.6, 1.9.9), did not help. I added a screenshot of what IntelliJ shows me, but if I understand the Ant docs correctly, that should work.

Comment: [Here is an IntelliJ error report with a similar stack trace.](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206251629-ANT-build-java-heap-space) Did the error also occur when running Ant from the command line?

Comment: I tried a couple thing and also your suggerstion with the command line. Now i got a more clear error message:  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.css.lims.versionserstellung.DictionaryChecker`. The confusing part is, that my ant script, which i used for my eclipse project works, while the script(its 100% identical) from my IntelliJ project throws the error above. Both scripts were started from command line outside of the IDE. My only idea is that i mixed up the dependencies in my IntelliJ project somehow, but that should not affect the build script(structure stayed the same)....I'm confused